# Merging two vectors into a third by even indices from the first vector and odd indices from the second

Tags: c++, vector, merge

I'm trying to merge two vectors into a third one by copying/merging elements at even indices from the first, and copying/merging elements at odd indices from the second.

Note: Both the vectors are two dimensional.

I have the following logic, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
void pattern::mergePatters( void ) {
  cout<<"\n This is Merge Patters"<<endl;

  patter_input.reserve( patter_one.size() + patter_two.size() );

  for( int i=0;i<patter_one.size(); i++ ){
    for( int j =0; j<patter_one[i].size(); j++){
      if(j%2==0){
        patter_input.push_back( patter_one[j]);
      }
    }
      //cout<< " patter_one answers["<<i<<"]= " << answers_p1[i]<<endl;
  }

  for( int i=0;i<patter_two.size(); i++ ){
    for( int j =0; j<patter_two[i].size(); j++){
      if(j%2!=0){
        patter_input.push_back( patter_two[j]);
      }
    }
      //cout<< " patter_one answers["<<i<<"]= " << answers_p1[i]<<endl;
  }

}

void pattern::printMergePatters ( void ){
  cout<<"\n This is printMergePatters "<<endl;
  for ( int i=0;i<patter_input.size();i++){
    for( int j =0; j<patter_input[i].size(); j++){
      cout << " Merge Patter["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]= " << patter_input[i][j]<<endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: Unclear how you want to merge. Example input/ouput may help.

Comment: You are potentially adding the entirety of `patter_one[j]` many times into `patter_input`. Seeing as `patter_one[j]` itself appears to be a vector, this is likely not what you meant to do.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you perform the actually copy in one loop, instead of using two.  This may be easier using iterators for the `patter_one` and `patter_two` arrays, but I'll use indices instead.

```
const unsigned int total_size = patter_one.size() + patter_two.size();
patter_input.reserve(total_size);
unsigned int p1_index = 0U;
unsigned int p2_index = 0U;
for (unsigned int i = 0U; i < total_size; i += 2U)
{
  patter_input.push_back(patter_one[p1_index]);
  patter_input.push_back(patter_two[p2_index]);
  ++p1_index;
  ++p2_index;
}
```

Notice the increment of the loop is 2 because there are two array elements pushed in each iteration.

**Edit 1: Copying odd and even elements**
To copy the even elements from `patter_one` and odd elements from `patter_two`, change the index initialization values and the index increments:

```
unsigned int p1_index = 0U;
unsigned int p2_index = 1U;
for (unsigned int i = 0U; i < total_size; i += 2U)
{
  patter_input.push_back(patter_one[p1_index]);
  patter_input.push_back(patter_two[p2_index]);
  p1_index += 2;
  p2_index += 2;
}
```

The requirements need clarification, so I presented two alternatives.  The amount reserved may not be correct depending on the sizes of the `patter_one` and `patter_two` vectors.  The above fragment only copies half of the `patter_one` and `patter_two` vectors, so your original `reserve` quantity may not be correct.

The reserve amount for copying half of the `patter*` vectors is:

```
const unsigned int total_size = patter_one.size() / 2 // Only even items
                              + patter_two.size() / 2; // Only odd from here.
```